Retrieve data from Docker Replica (Docker Swarm)
I have a TCP service running on an Ubuntu VM as docker container.
Due to load of devices I had to move from a single docker container to docker swarm with 3 replicas (for now).
I have a Django service which accesses this TCP service to retrieve data from clients connected to the service by sending a command (C2D command). With a single docker container it was working fine, but now when I am using docker replica, the Django service hits each replica randomly and most of the time I get a correct response after hitting service 3 times (I guess because there are 3 replicas so I have to hit 3 times)
Do I need to change something in docker compose file, which allows the replicas to interact with each other and return the correct response?
I want to retrieve the correct response on a single hit.
Here is what I have tried to fix this issue:
I have tried service discovery using consul but docker swarm was not registering the service. Although one single container was running fine with consul.

If you are spreading load across 3 containers, then you will need to query 3 containers for their state.
Your Django service can query "tasks."to retrieve the list of container IPs and then query each ip for whatever client data its holding.
